# Dashboard doesn't populate values after forking template django-oscars

Tags: django, django-oscar

here's my view.py of dashboard-

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    def get_template_names(self):
    if self.request.user.is_staff:
      return ['mytemplates/index.html']
    else :
      return ['dashboard/index_nonstaff.html','mytemplates/index.html']
```

So I'm successfully able to fork the app and extend templates but for some reason no values appears on the dashboard

[image: 1]

Comment: Did you run make sandbox and follow the rest of the instructions here? https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/internals/sandbox.html#running-the-sandbox-locally

Comment: Yes, I had followed it correctly. I've posted how I resolved it in the answers below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was following everything in the documentation correctly, finally figured out the error. In my settings.py I had put the path to my templates before the django-oscars default templates.

Below is a snippet of the correct way how it should be

```html
TEMPLATES = [  
'DIRS': [OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR, 
'path to/mytemplates', ],
```

Answer (score 3):

You have defined a new `IndexView` that does not subclass Oscar's `IndexView` - hence why the template fails to find any of the relevant context. What you currently have is just a plain `TemplateView` with no relation at all to Oscar's.

Assuming you have followed the instructions to [fork the dashboard app](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/topics/fork_app.html), you then need to subclass Oscar's `IndexView`:

```
from oscar.apps.dashboard.views import IndexView as CoreIndexView

# Note - you subclass CoreIndexView, not TemplateView
class IndexView(CoreIndexView):

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            return ['mytemplates/index.html']
        else:
            return ['dashboard/index_nonstaff.html','mytemplates/index.html']
```

See [this bit of the documentation](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/topics/customisation.html#start-customising) which explains how to do this.

That said, if all you want to do is override the templates (and not any view logic) then there is really no need to override the views. Just override Oscar's templates [as described here](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/howto/how_to_customise_templates.html) - so you can add a template `yourproject/templates/dashboard/index.html` to your project which will be loaded in preference to Oscar's default template.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've posted what error I was making :)

Comment: For what its worth, you answer doesn't actually address the problem you originally posted. The code you posted in your question would still not work even if you did change you `TEMPLATES` setting, and I've explained why in my answer.

Comment: For some reason, it was working! So, this was not the issue I was facing